# Регулярное выражение для выделения монома из полинома.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, полином

Имеется некоторый полином нескольких переменных, заданный в символьном виде, например

```
 x^2+y^2-4xy+6xyz-7x^3yt
```

Мне необходимо выделить коэффициэенты перед ним (если 1, то знак +, - или пустая строка, и аналогично выделить степени каждой переменной.

Следующее регулярное выражение

```
 (-?\d*)((?:\w\^(\d+))+)
```

успешно выделяет мономы из полиномов и разбивает каждый моном на две части: коэффициент и сам моном.

Но у меня не получается выделить степени монома. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбирайте текст каскадно.
Сначала выделите коэффициент и все литералы:

```
(?P<koef>[+-]?\d*)(?P<literals>(?:[a-z](?:\^-?\d+)?)+)
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/gL7hE9/1

Далее разберите литералы на единичный литерал и его степень

```
(?P<liter>[a-z])(?:\^(?P<stepen>-?\d+))?
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/kP9vI1/1

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сначала найти все коэффициенты и все остальное вот так:

```
(\-?\d*)((?:\w(?:\^(?:\d+))?)+)
```

А потом по полученным значениям (второй столбец матрицы результатов) найти уже степени, например, так:

```
(\w)\^(\d+)
```

Или выражение

```
(\w)(?:\^(\d+))?
```

Найдет переменные и их степени, а выражение

```
(\w)(?:\^(\d+)|())?
```

Если нужно пустое значение получить в массиве;

```
(?<=\^)(\d+)|()(?!\^|$)
```

Найдет вместо переменных пустые строки.